# Combining 3 imagemagick cli parameters into one ImageMagick.NET code

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, imagemagick.net

Hey all I have these **3 imageMagick scripts** (command line arguments) that I am trying to combine into Imagemagick.NET code.

**First (merging 2 images together):**

```
convert ^
( testingl.jpg -resize 610x440^^ -gravity West -extent 1080x440 ) ^
( testingr.jpg -resize 610x440^^ -gravity East -extent 1080x440 ) ^
blend_mask.png -blur 0x7 ^
-composite bothImagesMerged.jpg
```

**Second (Create 2 round objects with photo inside):**

```
convert lisa.jpg -resize 100x100! ^
null: ( -size 100x100 xc:black -fill white -draw "circle 50,50 50,88" ) ^
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -layers composite ^
null: ( -size 100x100 xc:"graya(100%,0)" -fill black -draw "circle 50,50 50,90" -blur 0x5 ) ^
-compose dstover -layers composite ^
-background none -gravity center +smush -25+0 ^
roundImageLisa.png

convert homer.jpg -resize 100x100! ^
null: ( -size 100x100 xc:black -fill white -draw "circle 50,50 50,88" ) ^
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -layers composite ^
null: ( -size 100x100 xc:"graya(100%,0)" -fill black -draw "circle 50,50 50,90" -blur 0x5 ) ^
-compose dstover -layers composite ^
-background none -gravity center +smush -25+0 ^
roundImageHomer.png
```

**Third (Write text on top of photo):**

```
convert -size 1080x440 xc:none -gravity center ^
-font arial -pointsize 40 ^
-stroke black -strokewidth 2 -annotate +-330+-150 "Lisa Simpson" ^
-stroke black -strokewidth 2 -annotate +330+-150 "Homer Simpson" ^
-background none -shadow 520x3+0+0 +repage ^
-stroke none -fill white -annotate +-330+-150 "Lisa Simpson" ^
-stroke none -fill white -annotate +330+-150 "Homer Simpson" ^
bothImagesMerged.jpg +swap -gravity center -geometry +0-3 ^
-composite  textOverImg.jpg
```

If I was able to combine all 3 of those then the output would look something like this:

[image]

I've tried to put all of them into a one-liner but can not seem to find the correct way (order mainly) into doing so.

I do have some code that produces the round images in C#:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("lisa.jpg");
MagickImageCollection images = new MagickImageCollection();
IMagickImage roundImg = null;

IMagickImage mask = new MagickImage("xc:black", 100, 100);
mask.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.White;
mask.Draw(new DrawableCircle(50, 50, 50, 90));
mask.HasAlpha = false;

roundImg = new MagickImage(bitmap);
roundImg.Resize(100, 100);
roundImg.Composite(mask, CompositeOperator.CopyAlpha);
roundImg.Draw(new DrawableStrokeColor(MagickColors.Black),
              new DrawableStrokeWidth(1),
              new DrawableFillColor(MagickColors.None),
              new DrawableCircle(50, 50, 50, 90));

IMagickImage shadow = new MagickImage("xc:none", 100, 100);
shadow.Settings.FillColor = MagickColors.Black;
shadow.Draw(new DrawableCircle(50, 50, 50, 90));
shadow.Blur(0, 5);
roundImg.Composite(shadow, CompositeOperator.DstOver);

images.Add(roundImg);
images.First().BackgroundColor = MagickColors.None;

IMagickImage result = new MagickImage();
result = images.SmushHorizontal(-35);
result.Write("lisa_round.png");

mask.Dispose();
shadow.Dispose();
result.Dispose();
images.Dispose();
```

Assistance would be great! @fmw42

Comment: I could possibly help combine into one command line, but I do not know Magick.Net.

Comment: @fmw42 I guess that’s a good start :). Btw who would be best to chat with on the imagemagick.net side?

Comment: Discuss that with dlemstra on the ImageMagick forum. Since you will be contacting him, I should wait to see if he solves it all for you.

Comment: See https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET

Comment: Alright @fmw42 I’ve posted. Hopefully I’ll get a reply from him.